# How to append a string to a list or array in a for loop in scala?

Tags: scala

```
  var RetainKeyList: mutable.Seq[String] = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]()

  for(element<-ts_rdd)
    {
      var elem1  = element._1
      var kpssSignificance: Double = 0.05
      var dOpt: Option[Int] = (0 to 2).find
          {
            diff =>
            var testTs = differencesOfOrderD(element._2, diff)
            var (stat, criticalValues) = kpsstest(testTs, "c")
            stat < criticalValues(kpssSignificance)
          }
      var d = dOpt match
          {
            case Some(v) => v
            case None => 300000
           }
      if(d.equals(300000))
           {
             println("Bad Key: " + elem1)
             RetainKeyList += elem1
           }
```

Hi all,

I created a empty mutable list buffer `var RetainKeyList: mutable.Seq[String] = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]()` and I am trying to add a string **elem1** to it in a **for** loop.

When I try to compile the code it hangs with no error message but if I remove the code `RetainKeyList += elem1` I am able to print all of the **elem1** string properly.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a cleaner way to collect all the string **elem1** generated in the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, your code is running on a *distributed* environment, so the local collection is not modified. Every week someone asks this question, please if you do not understand what are the implications of distributed computing do not use a distributed framework like Spark.

Also, you are abusing of mutability in all parts. And mutability and a distributed environment don't play nicely.

Anyway, here is a better way to solve your problem.

```
val retainKeysRdd = ts_rdd.map {
  case (elem1, elem2) =>
    val kpssSignificance = 0.05d
    val dOpt = (0 to 2).find { diff =>
      val testTs = differencesOfOrderD(elem2, diff)
      val (stat, criticalValues) = kpsstest(testTs, "c")
      stat < criticalValues(kpssSignificance)
    }
    (elem1 -> dOpt)
} collect {
  case (key, None) => key
}
```

This returns an **RDD** with the retain keys. If you are really sure you need this as a local collection and that they won't blow up your memory, you can do this:

```
val retainKeysList = retainKeysRdd.collect().toList
```

Comment: Thanks @Luis. Another question, How do I filter rows from the ts_rdd that matches those keys?

Comment: @VinothManamala probably using `filter`. Have you read the [**docs**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/) and have you taken a look to the [**scaladoc**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.package) to check all available methods.

Comment: But, for that to work, you may need to collect the data into a local data structure using `collect()`

Comment: Yes, I did try ```   val retainKeysList1: List[String] = retainKeysRdd.collect().toListval rdd1: TimeSeriesRDD[String] = ts_rdd.filter(c=>retainKeysList1.contains(c._1))
  rdd1.collect().foreach(println)``` . For some reason it hangs

Comment: Also, I tried doing this ```val ts_rdd1: Seq[TimeSeriesRDD[String]] = retainKeysList1.map(x => ts_rdd.filter(c => c._1 == x))``` but this gives me a list of TimerseriesRDD. 

Is there a way to do the filter on ts_rdd as whole using the list of keys?

Comment: @VinothManamala it probably hangs because you are collecting a lot of data, also contains on a **List** is pretty slow, you may want to use a **Set** instead. Anyways, if you have more question you may be better opening a new question, but remember to study more about spark first.